# Move text insertion point (caret) on click

Tags: javascript, html, textinput, caret

To enhance UX by catching miss-clicks in my form, I'm using the following code on a bounding box around each text field:

```
focusMethod = function getFocus() {           
  document.getElementById("myTextField").focus();
}
```

This works well in setting focus on the closest text field to where the user has clicked, even if not directly on the text field itself. However, the text insertion point (caret) is always automatically placed at the left side of the input, rather than the closest x point of the input.

Using vanilla JS, how can I take this one step further and find and move the text insertion point (caret) to the closest possible placement to where the user has clicked (assuming the field has text in it)?

Images:
[what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YlSu.png) | [what I want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ9Zv.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate what you need, possibly with an example? I do not understand your question, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @LajosArpad – thank you, I have edited the question to add images

Comment: rather than focus on the text field, try to simulate a click within the boundary of it based on original mouse position.  you'll likely need to handle actual clicks on the fields conditionally, and positioning based on browser window size may be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can overlay a sort of hacky text input that's larger, then use text positioning from it for the true input.

Otherwise, it's really, really difficult to figure out character positions... fonts are weird, and there's no way I know of in js to figure out exactly where they'll be.

```js
const byId = (id) => document.getElementById(id);
const on = (el, event, cb) => el.addEventListener(event, cb);

const textEl = byId("Text");
const hackEl = byId("Hack");

on(textEl, "input", () => hackEl.value = textEl.value);

on(hackEl, "click", () => {
  const charFocusPos = hackEl.selectionStart;
  textEl.focus();
  textEl.selectionStart = textEl.selectionEnd = charFocusPos;
});
```

```css
#Container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#Hack {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scaleY(5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  height: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}


#Hack.showOnHover:hover {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

#Hack, #Text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
  <input type="textbox" id="Text">
  <input type="textbox" id="Hack"></div>
</div>

<button onClick="byId('Hack').classList.toggle('showOnHover')">Toggle Hack Layer</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this. I have cooked up something that can be used as a starting point:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var testInput = document.getElementById("input");
var testContainer = document.getElementById("container");
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    testInput.focus();
  var padding = 0;
  console.log(event.clientX);
  console.log(testInput.getBoundingClientRect().left);
  console.log(testInput.getBoundingClientRect().right);
  if (event.clientX > testInput.getBoundingClientRect().right) padding = (testInput.getBoundingClientRect().right * 0.8);
  else if (event.clientX > testInput.getBoundingClientRect().left) padding = (event.clientX - testInput.getBoundingClientRect().left);
  testInput.style["padding-left"] = padding + "px";
});
</script>
```

and

```
#container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

#input {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 10%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/mLqj17xe/1/

The idea is to find out where should the cursor be and use that as padding-left.